# What are all the north american and European countries (airports) allows Indian passport holder transit without visa?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas

One of my employee wants to travel from Mexico to India. I would like to know what are all the North american and European airports allows Indian passport holder to transit without visa? He does not have US and Schengen visa.

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens?

Comment: @phoog: How is that page supposed to be helpful when the OP is asking about transit?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper for starters, any country for which an Indian doesn't need a visitor's visa also doesn't require a transit visa.

Comment: @phoog: So, what does that link have to do with the question? The OP is asking for airports in North America and in Europe that allow transit without immigration. The map in the article you link to shows that Indians will need a visitor's visa for all North American and European countries. Also, the article makes no statements on transit related to any North American or European country.

Comment: The North American countries are easy since there are only two (that aren't Mexico). Both the US and Canada would require a visa for transit. For Europe one might want to limit the question to the airports that receive flights direct from Mexico, since that is a more limited list than all of Europe. I believe visa-free travel is possible via Tokyo or Shanghai.

Comment: @Dennis The Carribean normally counts as North America. One might also sneekily try to include Denmark, via Greenland.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper As David Richerby implied, the OP might want to try to be creative to look for a visa-free itinerary through a Caribbean country, many of which seem to allow Indians to enter without a visa.  The other point of my comment was to try to give a nudge in the direction of doing one's own research.  I have been thinking of posting a proper answer, but I won't likely have time to do so in the next few days; I thought a marginally helpful comment would be better than nothing at all.

Comment: @phoog: I see. I was mainly confused because the inverse conclusion (countries for which an Indian needs a visitor's visa also require a transit visa) is not true, and thus (for an almost complete lack of any North American or European countries in the linked article that do not require a visitor's visa) no conclusion about where no transit visa is required is possible. [Another question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area), however, already contains quite some useful information on the topic.